# C++11 deduce type to return from gmock's EXPECT_CALL macro

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, googlemock

I had the following class and its mock:

```
  struct Logger
  {
    virtual void logWarning(string msg);
  };

  struct LoggerMock : Logger
  {
    MOCK_METHOD1(logWarning, void(string));

    /*! Sets expectation that some warning will be logged */ 
    void expectWarnings()
    {
      EXPECT_CALL(*this, logWarning(_)).Times(AnyNumber());
    }
  };
```

It works. The expectWarnings() method is used when I'm expecting some logs but not interested in them.

```
  LoggerMock mock;
  // ignore warnings
  mock.expectWarnings();
  // some code using mock
```

But lately, I've decided to add the ability to extend the expectations like:

```
  LoggerMock mock;
  mock.expectWarnings().Times(2);
```

So, I've modified the expectWarnings() method:

```
auto expectWarnings()
{
    return EXPECT_CALL(*this, logWarning(_)).Times(AnyNumber());
}
```

It's ok for c++14. But for c++11 it is needed to specify the returning type like this:

```
auto expectWarnings()->decltype(EXPECT_CALL(*this, logWarning(_)).Times(AnyNumber()))
```

Of course, simply putting EXPECT_CALL inside decltype() is not working.
What is the right way in c++11 to deduce this returning type?

Comment: Have you tried taking your code and going to definition of EXPECT_CALL?